# How do I make sure Windows 10 is using SSHD?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, performance

I have an SSHD with 14GB SSD in it. How do I benefit from this? Should I use the SSD for caching?

Below are screenshots of disk management & BIOS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What model is it? Usually it should be taken care of automatically as the SSHD manages what it puts in that space by itself. The manufacturer might have more information on how to utilize it effectively though.

Comment: The SSD implementations is hidden to the OS when a SSHD is used

Comment: I thought hybrid drives presented to the OS as a single device. (?)

Answer (score 1):

Intel Rapid Storage Technology and Intel Smart Response.

If supported by your chipset it should be available from your manufacturer's motherboard driver webpage.

Comment: Unfortunately IRST setup ended with this message: this problem is not supported. I guess whole thing is useless with this laptop.

Comment: What's the model number? I'll take a look for you.

Comment: It's an old "Samsung np530u3b" laptop

Comment: I can see something called "ExpressCache" here: http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP530U3B-A01UK from the readme: "ExpressCache  continues to enhance performance by using an SSD (solid state drive) to cache most frequently and recently used data." - note there's a 32bit & 64bit version and note the "A01UK" at the end of the URL, please find the page specific to your model.